# How do you to overlay a view with animation using Kotlin for Android development

Tags: android, kotlin, overlay

I've been spinning my wheels trying to get animation to overlay a view or button in this simple example.  After going down a few rabbit holes and making a bit of a mess with my code, I decided to press the reset button and start with a very basic example as I am stumped.

The details...

I am using the nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.xml.KonfettiView view to get the confetti animation and have that working with no issue.  I also have a button that will invoke the Konfetti functionality when invoked and that too works fine.  However, when the confetti animation is active, the button's real estate on the activity 'blocks' out the confetti animation.

Ideally I want to have the confetti overlay the button during the animation.  I tried using .overlay but could not get that to work, hence my reaching out for direction on this.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.KonfettiIt">

    <nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.xml.KonfettiView
        android:id="@+id/konfettiView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showkonfetti"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="show confetti"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Kotlin code...

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import com.ps.piggysnake.tactoe.databinding.ActivityKonfettiItBinding
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_konfetti_it.*
import nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.core.Party
import nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.core.Position
import nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.core.emitter.Emitter
import nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.core.models.Shape
import nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.core.models.Size
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class KonfettiIt : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var konfettiBinding: ActivityKonfettiItBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        konfettiBinding = ActivityKonfettiItBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val konfettiView = konfettiBinding.root
        setContentView(konfettiView)

        showkonfetti.setOnClickListener() {
            doKonfetti()
        }
    }

    private fun doKonfetti() {
        val party = Party(
            colors = listOf(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA),
            angle = 0,
            spread = 360,
            speed = 1f,
            maxSpeed = 10f,
            fadeOutEnabled = true,
            timeToLive = 2000L,
            shapes = listOf(Shape.Square, Shape.Circle),
            size = listOf(Size(12)),
            position = Position.Relative(0.0, 0.0).between(Position.Relative(1.0, 0.0)),
            emitter = Emitter(duration = 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).perSecond(300)
        )

        konfettiBinding.konfettiView.isVisible = true
        konfettiBinding.konfettiView.start(party)
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: From a quick glance, it looks like that's a regular `View` with plain `Canvas` draws, so you possibly just need to elevate the `KonfettiView` above the `Button`. IIRC, `Button`'s default `android:elevation` is `2dp`, but it moves to `4dp` on a press. Also, if you're supporting versions prior to Lollipop (API level 21), you'll want to move the `<KonfettiView>` tag to after the `<Button>`, as there was no elevation on those versions, and the z-order was determined by child order.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't just do this early, but I spun up a quick test and both suggestions do work. An `android:elevation="5dp"` setting on the `<KonfettiView>` is sufficient for the given example. You wouldn't have to worry about coordinating elevations, though, with the overlay approach, and it's even a bit simpler than I'd thought, since `KonfettiView` doesn't need to be measured: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Egbt1IVW5PAadqTckYEnoqhQ9C_RBIoD/view?usp=share_link.

Comment: @MikeM.  I set the elevation to 5dp for KonfettiView and that worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help.